# Example code required for how to access embedded .Net image resources in C#

Tags: c#, .net, resources

It's very easy to mark an image file to become an embedded resource however how does one access the image thereafter. Please can I have some example code?

Answer (score 12):

The most direct method:

```
YourProjectsBaseNamespace.Properties.Resources.YourImageResourceName
```

Answer (score 6):

1) [Adding and Editing Resources (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(VS.80).aspx)

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap1 = myProject.Properties.Resources.Image01;
```

2) [Accessing Embedded Resources using GetManifestResourceStream](http://www.attilan.com/2006/08/accessing-embedded-resources-u.php)

```
Assembly _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

Stream _imageStream = 
    _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
    "ThumbnailPictureViewer.resources.Image1.bmp");
Bitmap theDefaultImage = new Bitmap(_imageStream);
```

Comment: @bdukes: Not necessarily. Not sure how the `Bitmap` class works, but if it's like the `Image` class you can't dispose the stream until you are done with the image. And then you should dispose the image, not the stream. (At least if I have understood the documentation correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the third code snippet at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309403(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get the names of the embedded resource files;

List<string> resources = new List<string>(AssemblyBuilder.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames());

//Get the stream

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(
                AssemblyBuilder.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
                    resources.Find(target => target.ToLower().Contains("insert name here"))
```

You can convert from bitmap from the stream. The Bitmap class has a method that does this. LoadFromStream if my memory serves.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using https://www.nuget.org/packages/EmbeddedResourceBrowser/ library, there are code samples on the project page (https://andrei15193.github.io/EmbeddedResourceBrowser/). It's just to help access embedded resources in .NET applications. You can get a `Stream` to read the contents, it makes browsing resources a lot more easier.