# How to add some images to resources & can be used in form?

Tags: c#, .net

Iam using c# vs2010. 
For my windows forms project I have some PNG,Gif,Jpg images and I want to use in my program. For that once I added to my resources then is it possible to access from the resorces?

Because after to publish, I don't like, everytime copy to all of my users system for new images.

Is it possible to keep in resources and access it in program without copying to users system?

Thanks For The Ideas...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

There is a similar question in SO.

[Example code required for how to access embedded .Net image resources in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154262/example-code-required-for-how-to-access-embedded-net-image-resources-in-c)