# How can I include an image as a Resource in my project?

Tags: c#, image-processing, png, excel-interop

I want to add an image as a resource in my project so that I can reference it for programmatically inserting into a range in a spreadsheet.

I added the image by right-clicking the project and selecting Add > Existing Item...

I hoped that the image (.png file) would then be available using this code:

```
var logoRange = _xlSheet.Range[
                    _xlSheet.Cells[1, LOGO_FIRST_COLUMN], 
                    _xlSheet.Cells[5, LOGO_LAST_COLUMN]];
//System.Drawing.Bitmap logo = 
    //ReportRunner.Properties.Resources.pa_logo_notap.png;
System.Drawing.Image logo = 
    ReportRunner.Properties.Resources.pa_logo_notap.png;
_xlSheet.Paste(logoRange, logo);
```

...but using either Bitmap or Image, I get, "'ReportRunner.Properties.Resources' does not contain a definition for 'pa_logo_notap'"

This seemed like sensible code based on what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154262/example-code-required-for-how-to-access-embedded-net-image-resources-in-c-sharp), but it seems that the image has to be explicitly marked as a resource for this to work. How do I accomplish that?

### UPDATE

I tried this:

```
System.Drawing.Image logo = (System.Drawing.Image)ReportRunner.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("pa_logo_notag.png");
_xlSheet.Paste(logoRange, logo);
```

...but not only did I get a confirmation msg about the item being pasted not being the same size and shape as the place where it was being inserted, and did I really want to do that, it also inserted some seemingly unrelated text ("avgOrderAmountCell.Style") instead of the image.

### UPDATE 2

Okay, I tried this:

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.Drawing.Image logo = (System.Drawing.Image)myAssembly.GetName().Name + ".pa_logo_notap.png";
Clipboard.SetDataObject(logo, true);
_xlSheet.Paste(logoRange, logo);
```

...but get, "*Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.Image*' on the second line of that code.

### UPDATE 3

This works:

```
private System.Drawing.Image _logo;
. . .
_logo = logo; // logo (the image) is passed in an overloaded constructor
. . .
var logoRange = _xlSheet.Range[
    _xlSheet.Cells[1, LOGO_FIRST_COLUMN], _xlSheet.Cells[6, 
    LOGO_LAST_COLUMN]];
Clipboard.SetDataObject(_logo, true);
_xlSheet.Paste(logoRange, _logo);
```

...but I'm not crazy about it, because I'm using an image that is on a form, and passing the image to this class's constructor. Passing images around seems kind of goofy when it should be possible to store the image as a resource and just load the resource. I still haven't gotten that methodology to work, though...

### UPDATE 4

I reckon I'll just stick with what I've got (in Update 3), kludgy as it is, because this:

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream myStream = 
    myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(myAssembly.GetName().Name + 
    "pa_logo_notap.png");
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myStream);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(bmp, true);
_xlSheet.Paste(logoRange, bmp);
```

...fails with, "*Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have change the build action of the image to be embedded resource.

Then you can reference by doing:

**UPDATED**

```
 Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream( myAssembly.GetName().Name + ".images.pa_logo_notap.png");
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myStream);
```

[image]

Comment: By "myAssembly" do you mean something other than the project namespace? With this: "ReportRunner.GetName().Name + ".C:\\Projects\\ReportRunner\\ReportRunner.pa_logo_notag.png";" I get, "The type or namespace 'GetName' does not exist in the namespace 'ReportRunner'..."

Comment: Come to think of it, using the folder from the project seems sketchy to me, because at runtime no such folder will exist on the user's machine.

Comment: it's only going to be the folder name of the folder where it is in the project.  Like in my project its just an images folder in visual studio.  When published this folder doesn't exist on the user's machine.

Comment: Right, that's my point - since it doesn't exist, what's going to happen when that nonexistent folder is referenced?

Comment: Since you have a build action of embedded resource the dll that is build will have the folder pathing in it.  You don't make the math be the whole thing include c:.  For example it would just be images so the line of code would be myAssembly.GetName().Name + ".images.pa_logo_notap.png"

Comment: Please see Update 2.

Comment: Is the ".images." assuming I have a folder named images where I placed the image?

Comment: Please see Update 3.

Answer (score 2):

My method is to open Resources.resx under Properties. You'll see all your resources laid out on screen.

Click on the downarrow next to 'Add Resource' and you'll see the option Add Existing File. Choose your image name.