# How to access embedded .NET image in console application

Tags: c#, .net, image

based on this question:

[Example code required for how to access embedded .Net image resources in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154262/example-code-required-for-how-to-access-embedded-net-image-resources-in-c-sharp)

I'm using a console application, I'm trying to save an image in a variable but I can't access to the properties and resources of the project.

For example how could save the "Image1.jpg" in a variable?
[See photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN7wu.png)

Comment: If you open the properties of your project and go to the "Resources" tab it should create a `resources.resx` under the "Properties" folder. Those are your default project properties. Then you just drag and drop the image file into that, and on compile, it will be embedded in there.

Comment: if you look at the photo I have created some images, how can I interact with them?

Comment: Actual code access is `global::MyProjectName.Properties.Resources.resource_name` - but in case of an image I guess that'd give you a bitmap? The thing you linked to specifically tells you how to get it as byte stream though. So not sure what you're asking that isn't already answered there.